# pager inside fragment lose data when return from phone Call intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-viewpager

i have pager (detail pager) inside gridView whitch is (fragment A in parent pager)
and in other fragment B or C in side the parent pager i start phone call intent , when i back from the intent the detail pager lose content . . . 
the pager get the count of page but with out draw fragments

notes : the structure is

```
Pager {fragmentA , fragmentB, fragmentC,fragmentD , .... }
fragmentA {gridViewA}
gridViewA {detail_pager}
```

detail_pager lose content , just show white pages

Comment: Precise your question. Give us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem by using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and

```
  @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;}
```

and rebuild the adapter on page_selected in the parent class